# Proving that the matrix of the $- \theta$ rotation has to be used to establish the equation of a curve rotated by $\theta$ radians counterclockwise.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, analytic-geometry

Below is an attempt at proving that if a curve satisfies an equation $ f(X,Y)= 0$ , its image under a ***counterclockwise*** rotation by $\theta$ radians is defined by the equation :

$$f(  x cos \space \theta + y sin \space\theta ,  y cos \space\theta - x sin \space\theta) = 0 $$

My question is : a) concerning step *(2)* how to prove in a more formal way ( less relying on intuition)  the fact that the matrix to be used is the matrix defining a ***clockwise*** rotation ( though the curve is defined as a rotated counterclockwise one)? b) also, concerning step *(5)*, is it admissible to turn the column vector into an ordered pair?

I think this question is somewhat related to the fact that vectors are contravariant. Is it the case, and how to make this statement more precise, if true?

---

**(1)** Let $C$ be a curve defined by the equation :

$$ f(X,Y)= 0 , $$

for example $Y- cos(X) = 0 \space \space ( \iff  Y= cos(X) ) $ , or $ (X^2 / 5² +  Y^2 /3^2) -1 = 0 . $

**(2)** Let $C'$ be the image of curve $C$ under a rotation of $\theta$ radians counterclockwise.

One can define $C'$ as the set of all points $P=(x,y)$ such that the image of $P$ under a ***clockwise*** rotation of $ \theta$ radians satisfies the equation $f(x,y)=0$.

**(3)** The matrix of a clockwise $\theta$ radians rotation can be found by asking what are the images of the basis vectors $e_1 = \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    1 \\
    0 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$ and $e_2 = \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    0 \\
    1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$ under a clockwise $\theta$ rotation .  Vector $e_1$ is mapped to $\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    cos \theta \\
    - sin\theta \\
  \end{array}
\right)$ and vector $e_2$ is mapped to $\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    sin \theta \\
    cos\theta \\
  \end{array}
\right)$.

Consequently, the matrix of a clockwise rotation by $\theta$ radians is : $\begin{bmatrix}cos \theta & sin \theta\\- sin\theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}$ ( that is, the columns of this matrix are the images of $e_1$ and $e_2$ under a $ - \space\theta $ rotation).

**(4)** Now, we can restate the definition of curve $C'$ as follows. $C'$ is the set of all points $(x,y)$ such that :

$$f \Bigg{(} \begin{bmatrix}cos \theta & sin \theta\\- sin\theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}  \left(
  \begin{array}{c}   
    x\\
    y\\
  \end{array}
\right)  \Bigg {)}=0$$

that is

$$f \Bigg {(} \left(
  \begin{array}{c}   
    x cos \theta + y sin \theta\\
    x ( - sin \theta) + y cos \theta\\
  \end{array}
\right) \Bigg {)} =0$$.

**(5)** If we finally allow ourselves to turn the column vector (defining the image of point $P$ under the clockwise rotation)  into an ordered pair, we therefore can write that the equation of $C'$ is :

$$ f(  x cos \space \theta + y sin \space\theta ,  y cos \space\theta - x sin \space\theta) = 0 $$.

For example, the image of the cosine curve will be defined by :

$$[y cos \space\theta - x sin \space\theta] - [cos( x cos \space \theta + y sin \space\theta)] =0$$.

Comment: The theorem is true for any transformation. The proof is trivial if you transform the coordinates, rather than the curve.

Comment: What is the standard designation for this theorem?

Comment: This is just the connection between basis and coordinate transforms. To produce the rotated curve is the same as constructing the same curve starting from a rotated basis. This then is the same as changing the construction, that is the equation, to use inverse rotated coordinates.

Comment: I don't know if there is a name for it. But if you have a change of coordinates: ${\mathbf X'}=M({\mathbf X})$, with its inverse ${\mathbf X}=M^{-1}({\mathbf X'})$, then  the equation of the curve in the old coordinates $f({\mathbf X})=0$ becomes by substitution $f(M^{-1}({\mathbf X'}))=0$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.